# Vault Sealed Status is changing frequently

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

From consul UI,I can see that vault sealed status changing pretty frequently which is strange. It appears to be ***Sealed*** from Consul GUI because of which it shows the node to be in critical state. Which actually should be ***UnSealed***
[image]

But while on the vault node ,the sealed status appears to be *false* as expected but somehow the status is not getting replicated the same

[image].

Can someone let me know what could be possible issue and also help me in fixing this issue ?

Comment: what endpoint is the commandline `vault status` hitting? It's possible the vault command is just hitting the `VAULT_ADDR` of `vault.service.consul` - which will always be unsealed if you're running in HA

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this before and the reason is because the **unseal hasn't taken place on all nodes of the Vault cluster**. If you SSH into another node in the Vault cluster and run a `vault status`, you will see that it is still sealed.

This is the reason for the 'Sealed Status' to flash as green in Consul.

For the initial unseal, all 3 nodes must be unsealed. If the Vault is sealed after this initial unseal, the unseal will only need to take place from 1 of the Vault cluster.

**Steps to solve:**

*vault0*:

`export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200` 
(assuming https isn't active, this points Vault to the local Vault API)

`vault unseal {unseal key here}` (xN for the initial unseal)

*vault1*:
Repeat^^

*vault2*:
Repeat^^

The initial unseal is important, after this, it's not required to unseal all nodes. Also, think long and hard before automating the unseal, these unseal keys are the key to everything so handle with care.